# How to pass variable from save method to view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to display message with information if form was successfuly saved in database. Since there are many different forms in my website I want to write custom save method and pass variable to view every time save method was called.

I tried to use global for creating global variable when saving and then catch it in view and pass to template.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    global some_var
    some_var = True
    super(ModelName, self).save()
```

But this does not allow me to get some_var in view after I save model. I understand that making variables global is not best practice but could not figure out anything better.

UPDATE:

views.py

```
from .forms import modForm

def func(request, passed_id):
mod_obj = ModelName.objects.get(pk=passed_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mod_form = modForm(request.POST, instance = mod_obj)
        mod_form.save()
return render(request, 'template.html')
```

I need to pass variable to template when form was saved. But since I have many forms writing this in views isn't DRY. Thats Why I wanted to do it in custom save()

Comment: Can you add your view code?

Comment: It's not just "not best practice", it's actively dangerous in an environment like Django. **Do not do it**. But you will need to show more information about what you are actually trying to do in order for us to answer properly.

Comment: I could by there are like 10 form views and adding code to every isnt DRY.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I need to display message with confirmation on page when form was succesfully saved in database. I dont want to do it in view I got about 10 views to change, thats why I tried to achieve it by writing custom save. I tried to pass variable to view->template every time I save instance.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood django views and forms. A form.save() does not do any rendering so it cannot pass any values to a template.

Comment: @e4c5 not directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is in the view; it is the view that is saving the object, after all, so it should know that it has done so.

However if you really want to do this in the save method, you could try just attaching an extra attribute to the model object:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.is_saved = True
    return super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now assuming that object is the one you are passing to your template, you can simply check `{% if obj.is_saved %}` there.